# SSRS Procedure has no parameters and arguments were supplied

Tags: sql, reporting-services, parameters

I have a report calling a stored proc. The proc has 3 parameters declared but I am getting the error "Procedure has no parameters and arguments were supplied" at runtime. I'm not really sure what else to do.

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspFirstCurveProcess] AS

    DECLARE @Period int
    DECLARE @Year varchar(4)
    DECLARE @FacilityID int;

    /*  SET @period = 4
    SET @FacilityID = 3101
    SET @Year = 2013;  */

    WITH Process_cte AS (

    SELECT  [FacilityID]
          ,[FiscalYear]
         -- ,[MonthNumber]
          ,[Measure]
          ,[SubAccount]
          ,SUM([MthAmt]) AS MthAmt
          ,SUM([BudgAmt]) AS BudgAmt
          ,0 AS [YTDAmt]

          FROM EVAL.dbo.FirstCurveProcess
          WHERE FacilityID = @FacilityID
                AND MonthNumber = @Period
                AND FiscalYear = @Year
        GROUP BY FacilityID,FiscalYear,Measure,Subaccount


        UNION 

    SELECT  [FacilityID]
          ,[FiscalYear]
         -- ,[MonthNumber]
          ,[Measure]
          ,[SubAccount]
          ,0 AS [MthAmt]
          ,0 AS [BudgAmt]
          ,SUM(MthAmt) AS [YTDAmt]

          FROM EVAL.dbo.FirstCurveProcess
          WHERE FacilityID = @FacilityID
                AND MonthNumber <= @Period
                AND FiscalYear = @Year
        GROUP BY FacilityID,FiscalYear,Measure,SubAccount --MonthNumber,


     )

     SELECT [FacilityID]
      ,[FiscalYear]
     -- ,[MonthNumber]
      ,[Measure]
      ,[SubAccount]
      ,SUM([MthAmt]) AS MthAmt
      ,SUM([BudgAmt]) AS BudgAmt
      ,SUM(YTDAmt) AS [YTDAmt] FROM Process_cte

        GROUP BY FacilityID,FiscalYear,Measure,Subaccount
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

please check with this format

```
GO
IF OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[uspFirstCurveProcess]',N'P') IS NOT NULL
    DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspFirstCurveProcess]
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspFirstCurveProcess]
(   
     @Period int
     ,@Year varchar(4)
   ,@FacilityID int
)
as
begin
//your code
end
```

i think you declared parameters inside the procedure

Answer (score 0):

Try removing "/*" and "--" from those lines you made as comments. Those are probably the lines it's complaining about. Those lines won't be executed and you included arguments using those parameters.

Comment: this a parameter specific issue...no comment related i think.